# iOS App document directory wasn't downloadable from organizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, organizer

The app was shown in the organizer, when i click on download button it shows **save** option. But it was not downloading(this was happening with iPhone 5S).

with iPhone 4 device, i was able to download.
[image]

Comment: can you screenshot of your organizer from where you are trying to download

Comment: What do you mean by not downloading? Screen shot and more info please.

Comment: Have you tried it using iFunBox?

Comment: @WildFire,@Ricky I have attached the screenshot,please let me know your inputs, if any..

Comment: @DurgaVundavalli it will not save the app, it will only download the document directory of the app. If its showing in organizer it means the app is installed in sandbox and must download the required file. Please check again.

Comment: @WildFire yes I'm trying to download the document directory of the app.(I have updated the title) still not downloadable in iPhone 5s.

Comment: @DurgaVundavalli are yo able to see the document directory in bottom view.

Comment: @WildFire no i'm not able to see